# how to decrease the font size of place holder in angular material

Tags: css, angular-material

I am trying to decrease the font-size of a place holder in angular material.

here is my code:

```
 <form class="example-form">
   <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
     <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
   </mat-form-field>
   <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
     <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
   </mat-form-field>
 </form>
```

this is code I have tried in css:

```
 ::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
      font-size: 0.8em;
  }
 ::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
     font-size: 0.8em;
  }
 :-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
     font-size: 0.8em;
  }
  :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    font-size: 0.8em;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this style. It must be put on a global style sheet like styles.css

```
 .mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-label {
   font-size: 0.8em;
 }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-playground-1c8n9u?file=src/styles/_variables.scss

Answer (score 0):

You may be modified your CSS like below:

```
.mat-form-field::placeholder {
   font-size: 12px; // Your desiered font size
}
```